# Efficient algorithm to generate all solutions of a linear diophantine equation with ai=1

Tags: algorithm, math, equation, linear-programming, diophantine

I am trying to generate all the solutions for the following equations for a given H.

With H=4 :

```
1) ALL solutions for x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 =4
2) ALL solutions for x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4
3) ALL solutions for x_1 + x_2 = 4
4) ALL solutions for x_1 =4
```

For my problem, there are always 4 equations to solve (independently from the others). There are a total of 2^(H-1) solutions. For the previous one, here are the solutions :

```
1) 1 1 1 1
2) 1 1 2 and 1 2 1 and 2 1 1
3) 1 3 and 3 1 and 2 2
4) 4
```

Here is an R algorithm which solve the problem.

```
library(gtools)
H<-4
solutions<-NULL

for(i in seq(H))
{
    res<-permutations(H-i+1,i,repeats.allowed=T)
    resum<-apply(res,1,sum)
    id<-which(resum==H)

    print(paste("solutions with ",i," variables",sep=""))
    print(res[id,])
}
```

However, this algorithm makes more calculations than needed. I am sure it is possible to go faster. By that, I mean not generating the permutations for which the sums is > H

Any idea of a better algorithm for a given H ?

Comment: Isn't the solution to what you posted unique? (`x_1 = 4`, `x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 0`)

Comment: If you don't give us the equation, we can't help you to solve it.

Comment: I assume that in addition to your values being integers you are also restricting them to positive integers? And I assume also that the four equations are actually independant rather than being solved together...

Comment: You are right. I edited the post.

Comment: So then your question is simply "for a given N, find all combinations of n strictly positive integers such than X1 + X2 ... + Xn = N"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [implementation](http://ideone.com/4Q2b1#ul_inouterr) in C++

**blah.cpp:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> ilist;

void diophantine(int n)
{
    size_t i;
    if (n==0) 
    {
        for (i=0; i < ilist.size(); i++) cout << " " << ilist[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=n; i > 0; i--)
        {
            ilist.push_back(i);
            diophantine(n-i);
            ilist.pop_back();
        }
    }          
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n;    

    if (argc == 2 && (n=strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)))
    {
        diophantine(n);
    }
    else cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <Z+>" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

commandline stuff:

```
$ g++ -oblah blah.cpp
$ ./blah 4
 4
 3 1
 2 2
 2 1 1
 1 3
 1 2 1
 1 1 2
 1 1 1 1
$
```

Here's an [implementation](http://ideone.com/SoFbX) in `bash`:

**blah.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

diophantine()
{
    local i
    local n=$1
    [[ ${n} -eq 0 ]] && echo "${ilist[@]}" ||
    {
        for ((i = n; i > 0; i--))
        do
            ilist[${#ilist[@]}]=${i}
            diophantine $((n-i))
            unset ilist[${#ilist[@]}-1]
        done               
    }    
}

RE_POS_INTEGER="^[1-9]+$"
[[ $# -ne 1 || ! $1 =~ $RE_POS_INTEGER ]] && echo "usage: $(basename $0) <Z+>" ||
{
    declare -a ilist=
    diophantine $1
}
exit 0
```

Here's an [implementation](http://ideone.com/nj4CF) in Python

**blah.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import sys


def output(l):
    if isinstance(l,tuple): map(output,l) 
    else: print l,


#more boring faster way -----------------------
def diophantine_f(ilist,n):
    if n == 0:
        output(ilist)
        print
    else: 
        for i in xrange(n,0,-1):
            diophantine_f((ilist,i), n-i)


#crazy fully recursive way --------------------
def diophantine(ilist,n,i):
    if n == 0:
        output(ilist)
        print
    elif i > 0:
        diophantine(ilist, n, diophantine((ilist,i), n-i, n-i))
    return 0 if len(ilist) == 0 else ilist[-1]-1 


##########################
#main
##########################
try:

    if    len(sys.argv) == 1:  x=int(raw_input())
    elif  len(sys.argv) == 2:  x=int(sys.argv[1])
    else: raise ValueError 

    if x < 1: raise ValueError

    print "\n"
    #diophantine((),x,x)
    diophantine_f((),x)    
    print "\nelapsed: ", time.clock()

except ValueError:
    print "usage: ", sys.argv[0], " <Z+>"
    exit(1)
```

Comment: **NB:** it can also be done [entirely recursively](http://ideone.com/OR4VZ) ~but something like this tends to be a support nightmare in the real world =)

Comment: Unable to understand many things in python code: (1) how your code takes 6 as input, (2) how Ideone.com is taking xrange(), when I  cannot use it there. Instead have to use range() each time.

Comment: @jiten sry about the lag in response; there is this vexing (possibly psychotic) SO mod that attempts to harass me (and some others who have been foolish enough to challenge his practices) everytime i log in. so these day i mostly just suck info from SO. sighs. anyway 2) i suspect your python implementation is Python 3, there is no `xrange` in Py3 but the `range` function behaves like `xrange` in Py2. and my example code is not using Py3.

Comment: @jiten 1) the example code is designed to receive an argument from either the command line or from standard input. the ideone online compiler provides a little box where one can supply the arg via stdin. hope that helps :)

Comment: &&who knows? maybe somwen, this recursive py algo might become an efficient solution. lol. @jiten

Answer (score 5):

As with many problems, the solution becomes much easier to find/research when some terminology is known.

The solutions to these problems are known as **Integer Compositions**, which are in term a generalisation of **Integer Partitions** (where the order doesn't matter, i.e. only answers that are unique under permutation are considered).

For example, the integer *partitions* of 4 are: 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 1+3, 2+2, 4,
whereas the integer *compositions* of 4 are: 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 1+2+1, 2+1+1, 1+3, 3+1, 2+2, 4.

There are a few implementations readily available (references to language-agnostic algorithms follows):

- Since you are working in **R**, [the `partitions` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/index.html) can generate partitions for you. You would need to find unique permutations of each partition to get the compositions (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422945/generate-all-possible-permutations)).
- If you are able to use another language (either by interfacing with R, or by precomputing the answer) then **Mathematica** has a function to compute Compositions: [`Compositions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/Compositions.html).
- **Sage** is free (unlike Mathematica), and also has a function to generate Compositions built in: [`Compositions`](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/combinat/composition.html). It is worth noting that this one is implemented using [*generators*](http://alexbowe.com/streams/), which may use memory more efficiently.
- **Python**: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244180/python-generating-integer-compositions) Stack Overflow question (which generates partitions, which you can then permute). I did something similar [here](https://github.com/alexbowe/simplex/blob/master/simplex.py#L106) (although it uses `itertools` to find permutations, which I then need to filter for unique permutations, so this could be done more efficiently by using a permutation algorithm specifically for *multisets*).

In order to understand the **algorithms** better (or implement them yourself), you could check out this incomplete but useful ebook: [*Combinatorial Generation*](http://www.1stworks.com/ref/RuskeyCombGen.pdf) by [Frank Ruskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Ruskey), which shows how to generate partitions in *constant amortized time* (CAT). Since you want compositions, you can also use a CAT algorithm for generating permutations (also in the book) to generate permutations of each integer partition.

Ruskey also explains how to *rank* and *unrank* them, which can be handy for storing/hashing the results.

I believe these are also nicely covered in Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming Volume 4A*, if you happen to have it handy.

[ElKamina's suggestion to solve it recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621500/477839) is a good one, but I wouldn't use this approach for large H; since [R (as well as Python) doesn't optimise tail-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208963/tail-recursion-on-r-statistical-environment), you may end up with a stack overflow.

Comment: Nice Answer. Do you know of a way (in r) to generate integer compositions by using only a given set of numbers? E.g. Make 20 by using only 1,2,5 and 10.

Comment: Thanks :)

Off the top of my head the easiest way would be to simply generate all of them using an existing implementation, then filtering out any that have numbers outside of the specified values.

If you need more speed, you could roll your own based on the algorithm that Frank Ruskey describes (although I'd try using a faster language with the easier approach first, and storing the results for later use in your R script). It was some time ago, so I'm no longer familiar enough with the algorithm to suggest exactly how.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not trying to simultaneously solve the equations.

You can either use recursion or dynamic programming to solve this.

If you are using recursion, just assign a valid value to the first variable and solve the rest of it recursively.

Here n is the number of variables and sum is the sum. cursol is the partial solution (initially set to [] )

```
def recSolve(n,sum, cursol):
    if n==1:
        print cursol + [sum]
        return
    if n == sum:
         print cursol + [1 for i in range(n)]
         return
    else:
        for i in range(1, sum-n+2):
             recsolve(n-1, sum-i, cursol+[i])
```

If you want to use dynamic programming, you have to remember the set of solutions for each combination of n and sum.

Comment: Can you give your algorithm in C like code ? This line is strange for me "print cursol + [1 for i in range(n)]"

Comment: @Ben In python [1,2,3] indicates a list and '+' of two lists concatenates the two lists. Eg. [1,2,3] + [4] =[1,2,3,4] . Let me know if you are still unable to understand this and I will post a C like pseudo code.