# Tail recursion on R Statistical Environment

Tags: r, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

Does R support proper tail recursion and where can I find documentation about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's quite easy to find out that R does not support tail recursion optimization:

```
f <- function(n) {
if (n != 0) f(n-1)
}
f(100000)
# Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Had tail calls been optimized to jumps, then this function would have terminated without problems.

Answer (score 6):

No, R does not support tail recursion.

Answer (score 6):

[This reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-April/060599.html), found easily with Google, suggests that R does not support tail recursion. Luke Tierney (R-core member and R internals expert) explains why:

> tail call optimization cannot be applied in R, at
> least not in a simple way, because the semantics of R provide access
> to the call stack via the sys.xyz functions and parent.frame and such.
> It might be possible to make some semantic changes, such as only
> guaranteeing access to the immediate caller, but there isn't much
> point unless/until the performance of the function calling mechanism is
> improved.

Comment: Just to be clear, that answer on R-devel was referring to tail call elimination. It did _not_ say recursion was impossible.

Comment: "Proper" tail recursion I was referring to "tail call optimization/elimination". Considering R is a full statistical package, with real closures and some Object-Oriented features more aligned to functional programming (as "generic functions" and classes to this "generic functions") than to "traditional" imperative languages, it seemed strange, for me, it doesn't support tail call elimination. Anyway, I'll just avoid to use recursivity and I'll use loops. No problem, at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is new functionality in the development version of R (as of October 2023) that allows R to support call elimination in tail recursion, using the `Tailcall()` helper:

From the [help page](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/f914bb8b3793f1bfc1083bf33bcdbe3902bb78be/src/library/base/man/Tailcall.Rd):

> Using `Tailcall` it is possible to define tail-recursive functions that do not grow the evaluation stack ... This *tail call optimization* has the advantage of not growing the call stack and permitting arbitrarily deep tail recursions.

The example from the help page, computing the log(10)-factorial:

```r
lfact <- function(n) {
    lfact_iter <- function(val, n) {
        if (n <= 0)
            val
        else {
            val <- val + log10(n) # forces val
            Tailcall(lfact_iter, val, n - 1)
        }
    }
    lfact_iter(0, n)
}
suppressWarnings(10 ^ lfact(3)) # first Tailcall in a session warns
lfact(100000)
```