# Avoiding Stack overflow with Ackermann function in R

Tags: r, recursion, stack-overflow, ackermann

I recently saw an interesting [Computerphile Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7sm9dzFtEI) about the Ackermann function and tried to recreate it in R, here's what I came up with:

```
Ackermann <- function(m,n){

  if (m == 0){

    return(n+1)

  } else if (m > 0 & n == 0){

    return(Ackermann(m-1,1))

  } else if (m > 0 & n > 0){

    return(Ackermann(m-1,Ackermann(m,n-1)))

  }

}
```

in the video, they implemented their own version of the code (in C, I think) and explained that it takes a massive amount of recursive computation for specific value pairs such as 4,1 and it took them 3 minutes to compute that value. If I try to recreate this in R with my algorithm I get a stack overflow:

```
Error: C stack usage  7971652 is too close to the limit
```

Is there a way to get the result for Ackermann(4,1) in R?

Comment: R does not do tail-recursion in an efficient manner (and I recognize that this is not truly tail-recursion), so it can (as you see) fill up the stack. There are techniques that can work around it, such as [trampolines](https://tailrecursion.com/wondr/posts/tail-recursion-in-r.html). When it is not truly tail-recursion (as in this function), they are limited and cannot (if I read correctly) handle it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13208963/3358272 (due to its ultimate reliance on recursion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible but probably quite complicated. If you write it like this (see below) it will not error out, but it will take quite some time:

```
sub_Ackermann1 <- function(df){
  i <- nrow(df)
  m <- df$m[i]
  n <- df$n[i]
  if (m == 0){
    r <- n+1
    df$r[i] <- r
    df_i <- df} 
  else if (m > 0 & n == 0){
    r <- NA
    m <- m-1
    n <- 1
    df_i <- df
    newrow <- data.frame(m=m,n=n,r=r)
    df_i <- rbind(df_i,newrow)} 
  else if (m > 0 & n > 0){
    r1 <- NA
    m1 <- m-1
    n1 <- NA
    df_i <- df
    newrow1 <- data.frame(m=m1,n=n1,r=r1)
    df_i <- rbind(df_i,newrow1)

    r2 <- NA
    m2 <- m
    n2 <- n-1
    newrow2 <- data.frame(m=m2,n=n2,r=r2)
    df_i <- rbind(df_i,newrow2)}

  return(df_i)
}

sub_Ackermann2 <- function(df){
  r <- df$r[nrow(df)]
  if (is.na(df$n[nrow(df)-1])){ 
    df$n[nrow(df)-1] <- r }
  else if (is.na(df$r[nrow(df)-1])){ df$r[nrow(df)-1] <- r}
  df_i <- df[-nrow(df),] 
  return(df_i)
}
Ackermann <- function(m,n){
  df <- data.frame(m=m,n=n,r=NA)
  if (m == 0){df$r <- n+1} 
  while (is.na(df$r[1])){
    if (is.na(df$r[nrow(df)])){ df <- sub_Ackermann1(df)}
    else if (is.na(df$r[1])){ df <- sub_Ackermann2(df)}
  }
  return(df$r[1])

}
```

It works on smaller values at least, and doesn´t crash on larger values. Maybe someone can show that this can´t work or *vice versa*, have ideas how to optimize it...

Comment: Nice! thanks a lot! Could you explain why saving the objects in a dataframe avoids the stackoverflow?

Comment: Well, instead of storing the requests which need to be handled in call stack, it stores it now in dataframe in RAM, so technically the RAM is now the limiting factor. Another option would be to write the same information to the file (csv/txt) to the hard disk.